# Is there a way to change this dictionary output?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Change my dictionary, this is the initial code:

```
bow=[[i for i in all_docs[j] if i not in stopwords] for j in range(n_docs)]
bow=list(filter(None,bow))
bow
```

Here is bow output:

```
[['lunar',
  'satellite',
  'needs'],
['glad',
  'see',
  'griffin'] ]
```

```
worddict_two = [ (i,key) for i,key in enumerate(bow)]
worddict_two
```

From this output :

```
 [(0,
  ['lunar',
   'satellite',
   'needs']),
  (1,
  ['glad',
   'see',
   'griffin'])
```

to this output:

```
 [(0,'lunar satellite needs'),
  (1,'glad see griffin') ) ]
```

Comment: Can you show us the ```bow``` variable?

Comment: yes i will post it in the code in a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
worddict_two = [ (i, " ".join(key)) for i,key in enumerate(bow)]
```

This would work. Use join to Join all items in a tuple into a string with space as a separator

Answer (score 1):

You can just join the list with spaces like so

```
worddict_two = [ (i,' '.join(key)) for i,key in enumerate(bow)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
bow = [
        ['lunar','satellite','needs'],
        ['glad','see','griffin']
      ]

res = [(i,*key) for i,key in enumerate(bow)]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
word_three = [(item[0], ', '.join(word for word in item[1])) for item in worddict_two]
```